# IIS Express Caching

Tags: asp.net, caching, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have a .Net project that started in Visual Studio 2008, upgraded to VS 2012 and is now in VS 2015. I'm having an issue where I update basic HTML in an ASPX page and when I refresh my browser, none of the changes are pushed across. This happens every time the project is opened and only gets the current version of the file on the first build. If I open the project, build the project, view it, any changes after this point are never displayed in the browser unless I completely close out of VS.

I did think it might be the browser but I've loaded a completely different browser (after clearing my local cache) that I hadn't used before on this machine and the page is still displaying the old information. So I feel like there is a setting somewhere in the project that got carried over from a previous version of VS that is causing the local IIS Express to not pull the latest ASPX file from the hard drive.

I tried to delete the .vs directory while VS was closed and then start it up but I had the same result.

How can I get my changes in VS be visible to IIS Express and then to whatever browser I'm using to view it?

---

Update: I recently updated a CSS file and those changes were immediately seen in the browser. So, it's only the ASPX files that are not updating when saved.

Comment: Browser Link troubleshooting guide can be found at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T102322/visual-studio-2013-2015-troubleshooting-issues-related-to-browser-link-feature So in your case, try to troubleshoot first.

Answer (score 1):

After some time and digging around, I found that this happened on my DEV server as well. I looked through the web.config file and this setting had some how been added to the system:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled" />
</system.web>
```

This **fcnMode** is a file change notification setting that communicates when a file has been updated so that the old information isn't served up again. I removed this setting entire (setting it back to the default) and it's working as expected now in all environments.

Some more info on this setting if you'd like to read the MSDN docs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.fcnmode